# UITableView crashes on iPhone when scroll down

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I am developing a `tableView` which is crashing when I execute it in my iPhone and I don't know why is this happening. In the simulator works fine. However, in the iPhone, the scroll is not fluid and smooth. When I scroll down just hiding the first row, it crashes and exits the app.

I found this lines in the Organizer console:

```
Sat Oct 15 23:22:54 unknown ReportCrash[33018] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[33017]
Sat Oct 15 23:22:55 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:WAY.MyApp[0xf392]) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error
Sat Oct 15 23:22:55 unknown SpringBoard[31481] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error
Sat Oct 15 23:22:55 unknown ReportCrash[33018] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2011-10-15-232254_iPhone-de-Ibai.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Any idea? I've tried setting the rows to 0 and it works fine. Then tried with 1 row and it starts crashing again. I also tried to leave the row empty - doing "nothing" in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` - with no info to see if reading data was the problem.

If this log is not helping, could you tell me which methods are called when scroll down? I thought it was only `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

The `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";

    ContactsCell *cell = (ContactsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (ContactsCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Person *persona =[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Introducimos en la celda los datos.
    [cell setCellNames:[persona name]];
    [cell setCellStates:@"En Donosti"];
    UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[persona pic]];
    if(contactImage != nil)
        [cell setCellPics:contactImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Doing some debug with `NSLog`s, the app stops working when calling the `[table reload]` (And I think that's the method which is calling when I scroll down).

Comment: Can you post your code for tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Hi joern, edited the post with that method, thanks.

Comment: Since the crash only occurs on your phone (limited RAM-memory) and not on your computer (tons of RAM) this is probably some sort of memory leak, som sort of loop is taking memory and not releasing it properly. Check out this tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/ this demonstrates how to use "instruments" to detect memory leaks. Very helpfull and will probably show you where in your code the problem lies.

Comment: That might be a reason but then you would get a memory warning in the console before the crash and the TableView would work in the beginning and chrash after a while. But Ibaivi writes that the App chrashes even when the TableView only has one row. So I think the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: In the ContactsCell.nib have you set the Class of the nib's main view to "ContactsCell" or are you using a UITableViewCell as main view?

Comment: Yes, you make a valid point @joern. I did a search now for the "Signal: 10 Bus error" that occurs and came across this thread which I think you hould have a look at Ibaivi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482876/iphone-development-where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-signals-received-by-apps-and-w . If you look at the first comment to Stephens answer you'll see the thread starter experience the same symptoms as you, and according to Stephen this is probably due to a "stray pointer" somewhere.

Comment: OK!! Thank to both of you! I didn't manage to use the Instrument to find memory leaks because I can't load the app from the Mac. Even when I run it from Xcode, it says "Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process". However, I had a look to my code and I found a NSString in a loop which was creating and not releasing in every loop! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you :)